# How to provide access to storage account in Azure using service principal

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-storage-account, service-principal

I have a account in Azure portal. When I try to access to the specific storage account, its says "Access denied" and unable to open the blob container.

But I have created the storage account using the service principal which got all access.

Now I want to view the storage account using my Azure user account.

Is there way to provide permissions using service principal?

Comment: Do you have the permission to access the storage account?

Comment: Azure Storage requires a key for authentication api / sdk calls (which you should be able to get to, either programmatically or via the portal, given that you have access to the subscription).

Comment: @DavidMakogon I think there're RBAC roles in picture which is preventing Karan to access the properties of storage account in the portal itself.

Comment: If this is about the portal user rights, then it's off-topic, because this is not a programming question. Contact Azure support.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, it seems that the special storage account that with firewall set or in the Virtual Networks. 
If "Allow access from All networks " is possible, you could choose that or you could add your localhost public ip to allow access it from the internet . For more information, please refer to the screenshot.

[image]